# AutoGuess text in TextBox in WPF similar to Excel autoComplete text

Tags: excel, wpf, xaml, autocomplete, textbox

I need to implement the AutoComplete functionality to the textBoxes.
I know similar questions have been asked before, but they're all using a list of the optional items that matches the starting character.

But I want something similar to what in Excel sheet.
For example:
If you typed in a cell word (Medicine)
If you wrote in a different cell in same column, "M" letter it shows an autocomplete word (Medicine) but the "edicine" is highlighted/Selected till you press enter, it accepts it.
I don't want the list thing because it rude my xaml because it has a lot of textBoxes in in Grid with multiple rows and columns.
Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solutions days ago. From telerik there is a control RadAutoCompleteBox does exactly what I need.